# Visual Studio 2012 Pro Power Tools class/method name hover tooltip

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, productivity-power-tools

I installed Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012 and I guess one feature is either missing or turned off. I mean the tooltip that appears when howering on the classname and method name.
Here are the screens of what I mean. This is from VS 2010.

[image: Name hover]
[image: Expanded]

How can I turn on the same feature in the Visual Studio 2012 or is it just removed from this version of IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solution Navigator has been incorporated into Visual Studio 2012 and is no longer part of the Productivity Power Tools extension. There also doesn't seem to be any way to enable interactive tooltips.

Comment: So what is the best way to find out my derived/base types?

Comment: I miss the interactive tool tips a lot.   An alternative is to use the Object Browser.   Bind a keyboard shortcut to one of the built-in "View in ObjectBrowser" Commands.  If you have resharper, the "ReSharper_NavigateToObjectBrowser" command works nicely.